# Persistent error sending FCM notifications through Firebase Functions

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, android-notifications, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send notifications to users in Android Application, written in Java, using Firebase Functions, but I am still getting this error in the Firebase Functions Console Log:

```
          Error: Messaging payload contains an invalid value for the "notification.title" property. Values must be strings.
at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:25:28)
at new FirebaseMessagingError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:130:23)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:486:27
at Array.forEach (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:483:32
at Array.forEach (native)
at Messaging.validateMessagingPayload (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:476:21)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:313:37
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Here is my Function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/send').onWrite( 
event => {
console.log('Push notification event triggered');

event.data.adminRef.parent.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
var valueObject = snapshot.val();

const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: JSON.stringify(valueObject.title),
        body: JSON.stringify(valueObject.message),
        click_action: ".WebsiteActivityNotification",
        sound: "default"
    },
    data: {
        title: JSON.stringify(valueObject.title),
        message: JSON.stringify(valueObject.message),
        link: JSON.stringify(valueObject.link)
    }
};
const options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24 //24 hours
};
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notifications", payload, options);

});

});
```

Here is my Firebase Database structure:

```
/messages
    link: "..."
    message: "..."
    title: "..."
    send: "..."
```

Here is my Service:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    String notificationTitle = null, notificationBody = null;
    String dataTitle = null, dataMessage = null, dataLink = null;

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        dataTitle = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        dataMessage = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
        dataLink = remoteMessage.getData().get("link");
    }

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    }

    sendNotification(notificationTitle, notificationBody, dataTitle, dataMessage, dataLink);
}

private void sendNotification(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody, String dataTitle, String dataMessage, String dataLink) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebsiteActivityNotification.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", dataTitle);
    intent.putExtra("message", dataMessage);
    intent.putExtra("link", dataLink);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationBody))
            .setContentText(notificationBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Activity to open tag in Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".WebsiteActivityNotification"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name=".WebsiteActivityNotification" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Services tags in Manifest:

```
<service android:name=".FCMService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And still doesn't work...
Every answer is welcomed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just print your value of `notificationTitle` and check weather it is not null

Comment: I tried to print the value, but I don't even receive anything

Comment: Here the problem is you are trying to set a notification with null value

Comment: Wait I'll add the answer

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: The application doesn't always receive the notification data (because of network's status change). This happens when sending notifications through Cloud Messaging. FCM always sends the notification data, but no intent can be defined when open the notification in the background. Try OneSignal instead. I am using OneSignal and it is much better than Firebase for Notifications. Good luck!

Comment: yes even though im only using data payload sometimes it does not enter onMessageReceived but the notification will be in the cloud function console. So because the network status is weak it does not send?

Comment: No, because of IP change; that will be a reason. For example, when the client (the user) close the Wi-Fi and change it to Mobile Data the IP will change. Even though the user changes back to Wi-Fi, the notification will not be received. Another reason I don't know, I didn't struggle too much until I switched to OneSignal